# Alignment off: A gap between inline-block elements with nothing in it

Tags: html, css

I have a pseudo-grid of inline-block elements to display on my homepage, but there is a gap between two of them which I cannot account for. There is no element, no margin, no br, no nothing that I can find between these elements forcing them apart. The inspect tools for Chrome are just highlighting the container behind when I mouse into the gap. I've tried fiddling with the margins, but I haven't managed to get the top left element (New Booking) to play nicely with the one under it (Membership Plan).  The margins of all the other elements are nicely spaced as I want them to be.

Fiddle with the code displaying the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/8b779myb/

Any suggestions?

```css
.home-container {
  margin-top: 120px;
  width: 800px;
}
.home-container a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #25561B;
  background-color: #F9FBF9;
}
.home-container a h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
}
.home-container #new-booking {
  height: 242px;
  float: left;
}
.home-container #new-booking #car-new-booking {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px auto 20px;
}
.home-container #next-booking {} .home-container #all-bookings {} .home-container #membership-plans {} .home-container #browse-bays {}
```

```html
<div class="home-container">
  <a id="new-booking" href="/new-booking">

    <img id="car-new-booking" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/car-new-booking.png') }}" alt="new-booking-image" />
    <h2>New Booking</h2>
  </a>
  <a id="next-booking">
    <h2>Next Booking:</h2> Time, Car, Bay
  </a>
  <a id="all-bookings" href="/my-bookings">
    <h2>View All Bookings</h2>
    <br />Bookings to Date: {{ user.num_bookings }}
  </a>
  <a id="membership-plans">
    <h2>Membership Plan:</h2> {{ user.plan }}
  </a>
  <a id="browse-bays" href="/list-bays">
    <h2>Browse Bays</h2>
    <br />Home Bay: {{ user.homebay }}
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: I didn't see the point as there's more context in the fiddle, but I'll edit my post anyway

Comment: Fixed.  I still don't see how that helps since you can't actually see the issue without displaying it such as in the fiddle, and the fiddle shows the code as well.

Comment: So has their own version of jsFiddle called stack snippets (I've taken the libert of inserting your code in one). While you're welcome to link to a jsFiddle example it should never be the sole source of the code in question. What if jsFiddle is down or goes away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this;

```
.home-container #membership-plans {
    float:left;
}
```

It will make the space between the element the same as the rest of your elements. It was just being pushed to the left previously by the other a's you've used. With the added code the element is supposed to be left and that's why it fixed your spacing issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/8b779myb/

Comment: I am sorry, but although this solution works in this particular situation, the explanation is incorrect. (see my answer below for the reason why it behaves that way)

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the CSS rule for `.home-container a`

https://jsfiddle.net/80phu3js/

(otherwise inline-block-elements are aligned by their baseline, which by default is the lowest text line)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

1) as Johannes already wrote, `.home-container a{vertical-align: top;}` because the default value is baseline.

https://jsfiddle.net/8b779myb/1/

2) Use `.home-container a{display: block; float: left;}` instead of `display: inline-block`. Floated block elements are aligned to the top.

https://jsfiddle.net/8b779myb/2/